# Input Color Dialog bigger than Container

Tags: javascript, html, css, input

I'm having a strange problem with a  in a Chrome extension. As you can see in the attached image the dialog where you can choose the color is cut and I'm unable to change color tone.

[Color picker dialog on click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i87QA.png)

I'm using bootstrap as css framework and working with react. Yesterday it was working fine.

[This should be the normal Dialog for a color input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvFWF.png)

I've tried to change display, container, using as standalone input but nothing worked

Edit: when moving the browser window in the main monitor ( i'm using a macbook m1 and an external fhd monitor ) the color picker works fine. Probably something related to browser API and monitor size

Comment: "Yesterday it was working fine.": what code did you change since then? You should add all relevant code to your question as an [mcve] preferably using the snippet `[<>]` tool.

Comment: Please replace image links with actually showing images, there is Image tag (CTRL + G).

Comment: @Andy I've changed a lot of stuff but nothing directly related to the input itself. 

I'm getting this error even with a simple <input type="color" /> tag

Comment: @MilosStojanovic it says my rep is too low